# QT drag and drop image from thumbnail to gridlayout (QVTKOpenGLWidget)?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I want to do drag and drop functionality inside my project. Where I have a list widget as( Thumbnails). And, I want to drag an image from the thumbnail and drop the image inside the grid layout as (QVTKOpenGlWidget). I have used this one code. But unfortunately i am not able to drag and drop.

code:

```
void mainwindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *e)
{
    if (e->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-dnditemdata")) {
        if (e->source() == this) {
            e->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
            e->accept();
        }
        else {
            e->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    }
    else {
        e->ignore();
    }
}

void mainwindow::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-dnditemdata")) {
        if (event->source() == this) {
            event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
            event->accept();
        }
        else {
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    }
    else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}

void mainwindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent *e)
{

    if (e->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-dnditemdata")) {
        QByteArray itemData = e->mimeData()->data("application/x-dnditemdata");
        QDataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

        QPalette pixmap;
        QPoint offset;
        dataStream >> pixmap >> offset;

        this->ui->view1->setPalette(pixmap);
        this->ui->view1->move(e->pos() - offset);
        this->ui->view1->show();
        this->ui->view1->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        if (e->source() == this) {
            e->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
            e->accept();
        }
        else {
            e->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    }
    else {
        e->ignore();
    }
}
```

Any help is very useful for me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?  The [`Qt` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) has numerous drag-and-drop examples.

Comment: I will try everything like mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event), mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event), mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event), dropEvent(QDropEvent *event). But, Its not working for me

Comment: first, I will enable(acceptDrop()) method for all the 4 viewports. Then I will apply all the method related to drag and drop event.

Comment: Suggest put the description _I will enable(acceptDrop()) method for all the 4 viewports..._ into your question with code instead comment.

Comment: @AmarKumar, from your code I see that you reimplement the MainWindow's Drag/Drop events. Shouldn't you reimplement the QOpenGlWidget's Drag/Drop events instead? Let me prepare an example for you to show you what I mean.

Comment: ok, thanks. i will try this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause

You are reimplementing the drag/drop event handlers of *mainwindow*. However the four OpenGL widgets are on top of the main window, hence no drag/drop events will be generated for it.

## Solution

My solution would be to inherit from *QOpenGLWidget* and reimplement its event handlers:

```
#include "OpenGlWidget.h"
#include <QDragEnterEvent>

OpenGlWidget::OpenGlWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void OpenGlWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    event->accept();
}

void OpenGlWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    // do something
}
```

**Note:** `setAcceptDrops(true);` and `event->accept();` are important in order to allow the widget to accept drop events.

## Example

I have made an example for you, according to the task description you have provided. It allows icons from a *QListWidget* on the left to be dragged and dropped on one of the four OpenGL widgets arranged in a grid layout on the right. The dragged and dropped icon is then displayed in the corresponding OpenGL widget.

The full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-DragDrop).

Comment: we need to create separate .cpp file for Drag/Drop Or we can take this inside the mainwindow.cpp file.

Comment: @AmarKumar, yes, you need to subclass _QOpenGLWidget_ and then handle the events there. Please see the additional example I've just posted.

Comment: When I try to create a new file. I am getting error( QVTKOpenGlWidget have some other used)

Comment: @AmarKumar, what do you mean by _when I try to create a new file_? Your question does not mention the creation of files. If this worked for you, but you have another problem, please accept the answer (and consider upvoting it if you like it) and ask another question about the next problem you have.

Comment: I will go through the github link and try to execute the all model in Qt. But i am facing the problem in loading the image inside the list. Name show but image not uploaded . so, i am not able to check drag and drop are working or not. Please check it once.

Comment: @AmarKumar 1. Follow the link; 2. Click _Clone or download_; 3. Extract to a folder of choice; 4. Navigate to _src_ and double click _DragDrop.pro_. 5. In QtCreator go to _Projects_ and click _Configure project_. 6. Build and run the project.

Comment: image are selected only corner of the QVTKOpenGlWidget . But i want to display image in center

Comment: @AmarKumar, change the coordinates `(0, 0)` in `painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, m_pixmap);` to whatever position you want to show the image in.

Comment: when i change coordinate (0,0) to (100,100). in the full viewer image will be show but in the minimze view it will not show. Just check it once again

Comment: @AmarKumar, aparently you have to take the window size into account.

Comment: Hello sir I will ask another question related to what u said to me. Please see once

Comment: hello sir @scopchanov i have some problem with this code.

Comment: @AmarKumar, how can I help you?

Comment: thank you for your help @scopchanov.. now i am able to drag and drop thumbnails image inside the view port